# what is difference between StartupFolder and registry key

Tags: wix, registry, startup, wix3.5, autostart

I want to add my program to autostart. And see 2 ways to do it:

1. Add registry key to HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
2. Add program to Startup.

Which way is more appropriate and careful with WiX?

Comment: I would use method 2 and not mess with the registry as it is more safer, unless of course you are an expert with modifying registry. In that case I would make a backup first as a fail safe.

Answer (score 0):

I would absolutely recommend adding to Startup. Windows Installer is capable of handling different environments, different operating systems, etc. Even if it turns out that both solutions are 100% equivalent today, if something changes in the future, Windows Installer will very likely be upgraded to handle the new distinction. The registry will not.